# Initialisation of ImageView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to display the bitmap in an ImageView.

The following XML code is the ImageView.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

I lateinit the image view in MainActivity class as:

```
private lateinit var image: ImageView
```

I have perfect bitmap, there is no error in bitmap. The bitmap is passed from the a view kotlin class to the MainActivity.kt's "show_result" function.
The following function is in MainActivity.kt

```
fun show_result(bm: Bitmap){
    image = findViewById(R.id.image)
    image.setImageBitmap(bm)
    }
```

Then,
I got the following error, when I called the show_result function.
Error:

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:152)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:655)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:839)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:630)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:223)
        at com.app.symbolrecogniser.MainActivity.show_result(MainActivity.kt:75)
        at com.app.symbolrecogniser.CanV.saveBitmap(CanV.kt:424)
        at com.app.symbolrecogniser.CanV.touchUp(CanV.kt:196)
        at com.app.symbolrecogniser.CanV.onTouchEvent(CanV.kt:117)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11776)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:448)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1829)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3307)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:410)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4795)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6596)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6764)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.Mess
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.symbolrecogniser, PID: 8853
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:152)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:655)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:839)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:630)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:223)
        at com.app.symbolrecogniser.MainActivity.show_result(MainActivity.kt:75)
        at com.app.symbolrecogniser.CanV.saveBitmap(CanV.kt:424)
        at com.app.symbolrecogniser.CanV.touchUp(CanV.kt:196)
        at com.app.symbolrecogniser.CanV.onTouchEvent(CanV.kt:117)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11776)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:448)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1829)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3307)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:410)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4795)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6596)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6764)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var image: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun show_result(bm: Bitmap){
        image = findViewById(R.id.image)
        image.setImageBitmap(bm)
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/canv_fix"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/probability"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line in the log typically means that you are referencing a view that the activity or fragment hasn't loaded, so it returns null.

```
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:152)
```

This line is narrows down where the problem is in the code.

```
at com.app.symbolrecogniser.MainActivity.show_result(MainActivity.kt:75)
```

The problem is the image = findViewById(...), this view isn't loaded in the activity that's calling it.

Comment: Ok. When I use the image = findViewById(R.id.image) in onCreate function, the view is loaded and it's working fine. But If I use the image = findViewById(R.id.image) in a another public function, it gives error. So, Is any other way to create image view or to display the bitmap in a particular image view? or How do I use the image = findViewById(R.id.image) in a function?

Comment: Is that function located in the same class as the activity that is loading the Layout?

Comment: yes, the show_result function is in the MainActivity class.

Comment: can you add the main activity and the xml file to your question?

Comment: I added the main activity and the xml file code to my question.

Comment: In a CanV class file. This is a layout class.

Comment: There is no reference to a canV class in the MainActivity, is your project posted on github, I might need to see the full app.

Comment: How to make reference to CanV class in the MainActivity.

Comment: val canV = CanV( "provide the arguments"), The MainActivity is going to be the first thing that loads and from there you should be calling classes. I'm afraid I'm not going to be of much help after this unless you are willing to share your code.

Comment: I don't know what CanV is, but you can't call ``findViewById`` before ``setContentView`` has run (in ``onCreate``). One thing you could do is set an ``initialised`` flag in ``onCreate``, and have ``show_result`` check if it's set before trying to find the view. But ideally, nothing should be messing with the activity before it's initialised, so maybe look at this CanV thing and check it's set up correctly

Comment: I tried like you said val canV = CanV( "provide the arguments"). Here I don't know the what is the value of AttributeSet.

this is my Constrint layout class:
class CanV(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet): View(context){ ..... }

Comment: context is asking for the context of activity (context = this), 
attributeSet this is the xml attributes, I believe you need to pass the ImageView attributes, I'm Not entirely sure how to do that.  
The CanV class is extending View class, the View Class is taking the context that is passed into the CanV class.

Comment: Yeah, I know the attribute set is that image view attributes, but I don't know how to arrange those attributes and how to pass as attribute set.

Comment: You should create a new question, for that.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the efforts, Shawn!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64406886/how-to-create-view-class-object-in-kotlin-what-is-attributeset-how-to-create-i