# How to create View class object in Kotlin? What is AttributeSet? How to create it for a view?

Tags: android, kotlin

In Android, I have two class files, MainActivity and CanV.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

CanV.kt, This is a View class.

```
class CanV(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet): View(context){ ... }
```

CanV view in activity_main.xml

```
<com.app.app_name.CanV
            android:id="@+id/cans"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">
</com.app.app_name.CanV>
```

Now I want to create CanV class object in MainActivity.
I came to try:
`val c: CanV = CanV(this, ?)`

But, I don't know the AttributeSet parameter value. How do I create and pass the AttributeSet of CanV view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to create instances of `CanV` from both XML and Java/Kotlin, you should provide two constructors:

```
class CanV : View {

   constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
   constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

   ...
}
```

The first can be used from Kotlin (`val v: CanV = CanV(this)`), and the second is used automatically when inflating from XML.